# Triangle Quadrilateral and pentagon whose areas form a set of consecutive positive integers.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, area, integers

Find a triangle, quadrilateral and pentagon with integer side lengths whose areas form a set of three consecutive positive integers.  Make the areas as small as possible subject to these constraints.  Report you answer by giving the areas of each figure with the side lengths of those figure?

We use a rectangle for our quadrilateral with base $= 7$ and height $= 1$ to get an area of $7$.

We can use a triangle with $b = 1$, $h =12$ and legs $= 12$ to get an area of $6$.

We use a pentagon with side length $= 1$ and height $= 2$ to get an area of $5$.

This would leave us with our consecutive integers of $5, 6, 7$.

Does the height for the pentagon matter in this case?

Can we make these any smaller?  The problem seems too simple to solve am I missing something concerning the geometric properties of these shapes?

Comment: The pentagon claim does not seem right

Comment: Sorry, side length = 1, and height = 2.  I broke it into 5 triangles and calculated the are of one and multiplied it by 5.

Comment: In this case the height can not be 2. Did you try to draw it as a pentagon? The height is less than 1.

Comment: Yes, I see I neglected to calculate the actual height,  Wouldn't the height never be an integer though therefore never making the answer an integer?

Comment: You have a triangle 72, 54, 54. You need to get the height be an integer when the base is an integer. But it could be a non perfect pentagon.

Comment: What is the source of this problem, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can do 4, 5, 6.

4 = a 2×2 square
6 = a 3-4-5 triangle

5 = the above triangle with a 1×1 square chipped out of the right angle vertex making a pentagon.  The chip fits in the interior of the triangle.

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, a $3-4-5$ triangle,a $1\times 5$ rectangle, and a pentagon by deleting a $1\times 2$ rectangle from the corner of a $3-4-5$ triangle.

Comment: Since your triangle seems to be the Heronian triangle of smallest area (I don't have found a proof for this) one cannot do better.

Comment: The 3-4-5 triangle is in fact the smallest Heron triangle.  See fir instance mathworld.wolfram.com/HeronianTriangle.html.  As Chung Tak points out, the minimal solution is not unique.

Answer (score 3):

My attempt is using the lowest primitive Pythagorean triples $(3,4,5)$
[image]