# Is there a regular pentagon with integer area?

Tags: geometry, integers

Searching for an answer with a regular pentagon to the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659301/triangle-quadrilateral-and-pentagon-whose-areas-form-a-set-of-consecutive-positi)   I have unexpectedly the pertinent following question:

**is there a regular pentagon with integer sides and integer area?**

According to some references in the Web the answer could be affirmative (see [this](http://www.math-prof.com/Geom/Geom_Ch_26.asp), [that](http://www.vitutor.net/2/1/4.html), and [other](http://www.vitutor.net/2/1/4.html) where there are “examples” of (side, area)$=(16,440),(24,991),(6,60)$ respectively).

However effective calculation gives, for example with side $24$, the area $990.9949….$ which is obviously not equal to $991$.

I think the precedent examples are approximations and there is not a regular pentagon with integer area but I can not  prove it so far.

Some help or a  counterexample?

Comment: Integer/rational side as well I assume.

Comment: If you start with any regular pentagon $P$, and let $A$ be its area, then for any scalar multiple $rP$ the area is $r^2 A$. So just take $r=\sqrt{A}$ and you get area $1$.

Comment: Presumably, you left out some condition (integer side length, integer vertices, integer something)

Comment: The area of a Pentago is $\frac 1 4 \sqrt{5(5+ 2\sqrt{5})}a^2$.  If $ \sqrt{5(5+ 2\sqrt{5})}$ is irrational $\frac 1 4 \sqrt{5(5+ 2\sqrt{5})}a^2$ will never be an integer for integer a.

Comment: @fleablood, ...if $a$ is an integer. Why should it be?

Comment: I'm assuming $a$ must be restricted to an integer otherwise the question is trivial.

Comment: @fleablood, no, it is not trivial. For example, the restricttion can be that the verices have integre coordinates.

Comment: You edited the question but did not clarify what conditions you are imposing on the penagon, Piquito.

Comment: @fleablood: your second comment is the reason for which I feel the given "examples" are just approximations and not integers indeed.The constant of degree four, even could be a negation for Lee Mosher's comment. Anyway, if I am wrong I would like a counterexample.

Comment: Well, it depends on conditions.  *Some* conditions must exist otherwise it is trivial. The OP gave examples of (side, area) integer pairs so I presume s/he assumed integer sides.

Comment: Lee's comment anwers the question as you wrote it, Piquito; unless you impose some condition, the question is entirely trivial.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: the conditions are in the post (hyperlink) from which this question comes: side and area integers

Comment: Don't ####ing require people to follow links to understand your question!!!!  If the question is important enough to post than it's important enough to include on the details **in one place**.  Asking me to navigate to another post when I'm trying to help is both rude and lazy.  DONT DO IT!  Now edit this post and state the conditions!!!!

Comment: One of the examples made an assumption that the radius = 5.  I have no friggin' idea why they came up with that.

Comment: First link (this): "So now if we were told the length of the other side,  
  we would be in business!  
  Say we are told it is about 4 (it's actually more like 4.1291)."  So we can toss that page as utterly useless.  We need to figure out the side and we need to know it *precisely*.  This is is .... garbage.  Next link....

Comment: Second link (that).  Not in english so... but it assumes the side is 6 and the radius is 5.  How it came up with radius 5 ... I have no idea.  By trig we can calculate the radius will be $3/\cos 54 = 5.103...$. Not 5.  So let's toss that.

Comment: This aren't even *close* approximations!

Comment: @fleablood: see gran_chat's answer and be happy. (I have edited for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we require the pentagon to have integer side length, then the answer is no. The area of a regular pentagon with side length $a$ is
$$5\cdot\left(\frac12a h\right)=\frac54a^2\tan(54^\circ)$$
But $\tan(54^\circ)$ is irrational, because [the only rational values of $\tan k\pi/n$ are $0$ and $\pm1$](http://www.oberlin.edu/faculty/jcalcut/tanpap.pdf).

Comment: @gran_chat: So, definitely NOT is the answer; I was looking for a maybe  "convenient" irrational radius giving a rational side (there are many examples). Consequently the "examples" in the web deserve well put its quotation marks. Thank you very much.